# Class accessor and mutator functions in c++

Tags: c++, function, class

I've been trying to write a program which takes integer value from user. The integer value will be changed by mutator function and another function prints on the screen. Thanks for your help. Here is my effort until now:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class bank 
{
 public:

  bank();

  void output(ostream& out)
  {
    out<<account;
  }

  int revised(int acc)
  {
  acc=acc+acc*2;
  }

  void set_account(int a)
  {
  account = a;
  }

  int get_account()
  {
  return account;   
  }


private:

int account;

};



int main()
{
bank obj1;
int i;
cout << "Enter your money";
cin>>i;

obj1.set_account(i);
obj1.output(cout);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question specifically? Please include a clear question so that you can get a clear answer. For example, is there an error you are getting that you need help with, or is your program behaving incorrectly?

Comment: What's your question? Does your code not work at all? Does it work partially? What output did you expect to see? What output are you getting?

Comment: My code gives an error at the functions part. I declared prototypes in class which  gives no error. But when reads the outside of the class it gives an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't pass the functions the argument type: `obj.set_account(i)` and `obj.output(cout)` are sufficient. Notice that I passed `cout` instead of `out` because `out` is not defined in `main()`. Remember, the parameter name in the function definition/declaration has nothing to do with the name of the argument that you actually pass it.

You're also missing return types for your function definitions.

Furthermore, you should pass the `ostream` by reference, not by value, because `ostream` does not define a copy ctor.

Comment: Thank you so much. I edited my question with your suggestions. But now it gives an error: undefined reference to bank::bank

Comment: you've declared the `bank()` constructor but didn't define it. try `bank(){}` or just remove the declaration completely and let the compiler generate a default ctor for you

Comment: Thank you so much I got it finally.